# GET 404, Axios in Vercel Deploy

Tags: reactjs, axios, vercel

When I test my project locally, it works fine and the posts are loaded from the server, using api context too, but when I use it in Vercel, the posts don't show up and I get this error in the browser console:
[image]

vite.config.js:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/posts': "https://serverbackend-br77.onrender.com" ,
      '/register': "https://serverbackend-br77.onrender.com" ,
      '/login': "https://serverbackend-br77.onrender.com",
      '/users': "https://serverbackend-br77.onrender.com",
      '/users/:id': "https://serverbackend-br77.onrender.com",
      '/forgotPassword' : "https://serverbackend-br77.onrender.com",
      '/codigo-contrasena': "https://serverbackend-br77.onrender.com",
      '/reset_password' : "https://serverbackend-br77.onrender.com",
    }
  },
  plugins: [react()]
})
```

Postcontext.jsx

```js
import React, { useState,useContext,createContext,useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import toast from 'react-hot-toast'




const postContext = createContext()


export const usePost = function(){
  const context = useContext(postContext)
  return context
} 

export const PostProvider = function({children}) {

   
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
    const [token, setToken] = useState("")
    const [userid, setUserid] = useState("")
    const [tokenCode, setTokenCode] = useState("")
    const [tokenResetPwd, setTokenResetPwd] = useState("")


    const obtenerPosts = async ()=>{
      const respuesta = await axios.get('/posts')
      setPosts(respuesta.data)
      
    }

    const createPost = async (pub) =>{
      const formulario = new FormData()
      
      for(let clave in pub){
        formulario.append(clave, pub[clave])
      }
      
      

      const respuesta = await axios.post('/posts',formulario, {
        headers:{
          "Content-Type":"multipart/form-data",
          "x-access-token": token
        }
      })
      setPosts([...posts, respuesta.data])
      
    }
    
    const obtenerPost = async (id) => {
      const respuesta = await axios.get('/posts/' + id)

      return respuesta.data
    }

    const postInfo = async (id) => {
      const respuesta = await axios.get('/posts/' + id)
      return respuesta.data.creadoPor
    }

    const obtenerUsuario = async (id) =>{
      const usuarioEncontrado = axios.get('/users/' + id)
      return usuarioEncontrado
    }

    const eliminarPost = async (id) => {
      const del = await axios.delete('/posts/' + id, {headers: {"x-access-token":token}})
      
      if (del.status == 200){
        setPosts(posts.filter(post => post._id !== id))
      }
      
    }

    const registrarUsuario = async (userRegister) => {
      await axios.post("/register", userRegister)  
  
    }

    const logearUsuario = async (loginUser) => {
      try {
        const {data} = await axios.post('/login', loginUser)
        setToken(data.token)
        setUserid(data.id)
        
        toast.success("sesion iniciado correctamente", {duration: 10000})
        window.localStorage.setItem('UsuarioLogeado', JSON.stringify(data))
        
      } catch (error) {
        toast.error("credenciales incorrectas", {duration: 10000})
      } 
      
    }
    
    const enviarSolicitudDeCambiodePWD = async (correo) =>{
      try {
        const {data} = await axios.post('/forgotPassword', correo)
        setTokenCode(data.token)
        
        if (data.messageError) return toast.error("direccion de servicio de correo electronico invalido (SOLO GMAIL)")
        
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        
      }
    }

    const enviarCodigo = async (codigo) =>{
      try {
        const {data} = await axios.post('/codigo-contrasena', codigo, {headers: {"token-pwd": tokenCode}})
        setTokenResetPwd(data.token)
        
        if (data.errorMessage) return toast.error("el codigo no coincide")
        else if (data.token) return toast.success("el codigo es correcto")
      } catch (error) {
        toast.error("el codigo es incorrecto")
      }
    }

    const cambiarContraseña = async (contraseña) =>{
        try {
          const {data} = await axios.post('/reset_password', contraseña, {headers: {'token-pwd': tokenResetPwd}})
          
          if(data.messageError) return toast.error("las contraseñas no coinciden")
          else if (data.message) {
            return toast.success("contraseña cambiada correctamente")
            
          }
          
          
         
        } catch (error) {
          toast.error("las contraseñas deben ser iguales")
        }
    }

  


    useEffect(()=>{
      obtenerPosts()
    },[])

    useEffect(()=>{
      logearUsuario
      
    },[userid])

    useEffect(()=>{
      const usuarioLogeadoJson = window.localStorage.getItem('UsuarioLogeado')
      if (usuarioLogeadoJson) {
        const usuario = JSON.parse(usuarioLogeadoJson)
        setUserid(usuario.id)
        setToken(usuario.token)
        
      }
    }, [])
    
    

    

    return <postContext.Provider value={{
      posts, obtenerPosts, createPost, obtenerPost, postInfo, eliminarPost, registrarUsuario, logearUsuario, userid, obtenerUsuario, enviarSolicitudDeCambiodePWD, enviarCodigo, cambiarContraseña
      }}>
      {children}
    </postContext.Provider>
      
    
}
```

Inicio.jsx

```js
import '../style/inicio.css'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import { usePost } from '../context/Postcontext'

function Inicio() {
  

    const { posts } =  usePost()


    

    return (
        
        <main >
            
            <div className='titulo-tema'>
                <b><h1>ESQUEMAS DE BASE DE DATOS</h1></b>
            </div>
                <div className='contenido'>
                    {posts.map((publicacion)=>{
                        return <div className='carta' key={publicacion._id}>
                                    <figure>
                                        {publicacion.imagen && <img src={publicacion.imagen.url} className="imagen" alt="imagenes referenciales*" />}
                                    </figure>
                                    <div>    
                                        <div>
                                            <h1><b>{(publicacion.nombre).toUpperCase()}</b></h1>
                                        </div>
                                        <Link to={`/items/${publicacion._id}`}>
                                            <button className='boton-imagen'>Vista Previa</button>
                                        </Link>
                                    </div>
                                </div>     
                    })}
            
                </div>
        </main>
    )
}

export default Inicio
```

main.jsx

```js
import React from 'react'
import  ReactDOM  from 'react-dom/client'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import Info from './categorias/Info'
import Cabecera from './components/Cabecera'
import Inicio from './categorias/Inicio'
import Ventas from './categorias/Ventas'
import Category from './components/Category'
import {PostProvider} from './context/Postcontext'
import {Newpost} from './categorias/Publicar'
import { Toaster } from 'react-hot-toast'
import Register from './user/Register'
import Login from './user/Login'
import Lugares from './categorias/Lugares'
import Empresas from './categorias/Empresas'
import Paginas_web from './categorias/Paginas_web'
import ReqResetPwd from './user/ReqResetPwd'
import Reset_pwd from './user/Reset_pwd'
import SendCode from './user/SendCode'

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))

root.render(
    <PostProvider>
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/' exact element={<>
                        <Cabecera/>
                        <Inicio/>
                        <Category/>               
                    </>
                }/>
                <Route path='/:items/:id' element={<>   
                        <Info/>
                    </>
                }/>  
                <Route path='/categoria-ventas' element={<>          
                        <Cabecera/>
                        <Ventas/>
                        <Category/>            
                    </>
                }/>
                <Route path='/categoria-lugares' element={<>          
                        <Cabecera/>
                        <Lugares/>
                        <Category/>            
                    </>
                }/>
                <Route path='/categoria-empresas' element={<>          
                        <Cabecera/>
                        <Empresas/>
                        <Category/>            
                    </>
                }/>
                <Route path='/categoria-paginasweb' element={<>          
                        <Cabecera/>
                        <Paginas_web/>
                        <Category/>            
                    </>
                }/>
                
                <Route path='/new' element={<>             
                    <Newpost/>
                </>}/>
                <Route path='/registrar' element={<>             
                    <Register/>
                </>}/>
                <Route path='/logear' element={<>             
                    <Login/>
                </>}/>
                <Route path='/forgot-password' element={
                <>
                    <ReqResetPwd/>
                    <SendCode/>
                    <Reset_pwd/>
                    </>
                }/>
           
            </Routes>
            <Toaster/>
            
        </Router>
    </PostProvider>    
  
)
```

Here I leave my repository in github anyway: https://github.com/RoyDevLop/freedatabase
Here I also leave my website displayed with the error: https://freedatabase.vercel.app/

Comment: Well if it works locally then your deployment setup is not set appropriately. I see your `vite` file has a `proxy` to your `render.com` server backend, well the request is not being redirected at your server. You can see your data at [https://serverbackend-br77.onrender.com/posts](https://serverbackend-br77.onrender.com/posts) with `200` status. Maybe move the `proxy` inside your `package.json` or otherwise look up at Vercel docs for their own `proxy` setup.